# Firefox and Acrobat - what happened to the Acrobat toolbar?

Tags: firefox, adobe-acrobat

I just installed the latest version of Firefox and Acrobat Reader on a new Windows 7 box. Bringing up a PDF in the browser was a big surprise - the toolbar is gone! Where's the Save As button? Where's the zoom settings?

Was this a change to Acrobat Reader, or is there a setting that I couldn't find?

Version 4.0 of Firefox, version 10.0.1 of Acrobat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>, which is the shortcut to hide/show the toolbars, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, which is the shortcut to reset the toolbars to the default.